# How to change UITabBarSystemItemContacts in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, uitabbaritem

Currently i am working in iphone application, Using UITabbar to create five tabbar and set UITabBarSystemItem, When i select third tab, then i tried to change Custom image instead of UITabBarSystemItemContacts, but it doesn't work. I tried this:

```
 UITabBarItem *filterTab4 = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
    [filterTab4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this  self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first"]; in your third tab class init() it works.